# Django label_tag required asterisk

Tags: python, django

I am currently working on some Django templates and would like to put an asterisk after the label of required fields.

First of all I have found this syntax which works just fine but it makes me type a lot of code that is not required without the required asterisk.

```
<div>
    {{ field.errors }}
    <label for="{{ field.auto_id }}">
        {% if field.field.required %}<span class="required">{{ field.label }}</span>
        {% else %}{{ field.label }}{% endif %}
    </label>
    {{ field }}
</div>
```

This is the code I currently have in my template:

```
<div>
    {{ field.errors }}
    {{ field.label_tag }}{{ field }}
</div>
```

This way it saves a lot of code to write, but I can't figure out how to get the asterisk after the label with a required field.

Could someone help me with this?
If you need some more info feel free to ask.

Comment: Have you considered using [Crispy Forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) for rendering your forms?
It adds the asked asterisk by default to all required fields. [See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdXFD.png).
It also outlines in red the required fields.

Comment: As a matter of fact. The last year I have used Crispy Forms quite often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider writing a template tag that takes in `field` and returns `field.label` suffixed with an asterisk  if the field is required, and `field.label` if not. And you can use like so:

```
<div>
    {{ field.errors }}
    {{ field | append_ast_if_req }}
    {{ field }}
</div>
```

Your template tag can be:

```
@register.filter
def append_ast_if_req (field):
    if field.field.required:
         return field.label + '*'
    else:
         return field.label
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the `required_css_class = 'something'` on the form (cf [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.required_css_class)) Then using css you could add a red asterisk on the label